# How to make the word "Keywords" non-italic in the following template?

Tags: italic, elsarticle

How to make the word "Keywords" non-italic in the following template?

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{changepage}
\frenchspacing

\makeatletter % <-Added code from here
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{\textbf{Title of the Article?}}
\begin{abstract}
this is the abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\hspace{-0.2cm} life, book, social knowledge
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The italic formatting is hardcoded in the [`elsarticle`](https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) document class, so in order to remove it, you have to patch the `keyword` environment by inserting the following code somewhere between `\documentclass{elsarticle}` and `\begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\keyword}{\textit}{}{}{}
```

[image: rendered title page with "Keywords:" non-italic]